# CUDA Globel variables

Tags: cuda

How can I create global variables in CUDA?

```
__device__ float *devD;
cudaMalloc((void**)&devD, s);
calculateDT_T2B<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>();
cudaMemcpy(dtr, devD, s, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
print(dtr);
```

It doesnot give the correct answer (gives some random numbers). But when I call

```
calculateDT_T2B<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(devD); instead of
calculateDT_T2B<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>();
```

It gives the correct answer.. why?

Comment: Can you post the whole code ? Where are you declaring devD ? Is its scope truly global ?

Comment: How is this question any different to your other question on the same subject? Why shouldn't one of them be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use `cudaMalloc` to allocate onto a `__device__` symbol in GPU memory. When you do so, you are allocating only in host memory. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255215/global-variable-in-cuda/6255798#6255798) to your own, almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255215/global-variable-in-cuda) which you posted within a minute of this one. The short version is to use [cudaMemcpyToSymbol](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g58acd070e6f9bb82d7aeee3d0b958460.html) to write a dynamically allocated device pointer onto a statically declared symbol.