# Creating global variables in CUDA

Tags: cuda, global-variables

How can I create global variables in CUDA??
Could you please give me an example?

How can create arrays inside a CUDA function for example

```
__global__ void test()
{
  int *a = new int[10];
}
```

or How can I create a global array and access it from this function. for example

```
__device__ int *a;
__global__ void test()
{
  a[0] = 2;
}
```

Or How can I use like the following..

```
__global__ void ProcessData(int img)
{
   int *neighborhood = new int[8]; 
   getNeighbourhood(img, neighbourhood);
}
```

---

Still I have some problem with this. I found that compare to

```
__device__
```

if I define

```
"__device__ __constant__" (read only)
```

will improve the memory access. 
But my problem is I have an array in host memory say

```
 float *arr = new float[sizeOfTheArray];
```

I want to make it as a variable array in device and I need to modify this in device memory and I need to copy this back to host. How can I do it??

Comment: I need a global array and variable on device. How can I do that?? For example I am going to define PI=3.14... and I am going to use when I call device functions..

Comment: for example, an image width and height, I am reading the image using a host function and passing that to device function and I want to keep W and H inside the device memory so that I can access it from other functions without passing that as a parameter.

Comment: I want to use like this.    ___global___ void ProcessData(int *img){int* neighborhood = new int[8]; getNeighbourhood(img, neighbourhood);}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C++ `new` operator is supported on compute capability 2.0 and 2.1 (ie. Fermi) with CUDA 4.0, so you could use `new` to allocate global memory onto a device symbol, although neither of your first two code snippets are how it would be done in practice.

On older hardware, and/or with pre CUDA 4.0 toolkits, the standard approach is to use the [`cudaMemcpyToSymbol`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g58acd070e6f9bb82d7aeee3d0b958460.html) API in host code:

```
__device__ float *a;

int main()
{
    const size_t sz = 10 * sizeof(float);

    float *ah;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&ah, sz);
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol("a", &ah, sizeof(float *), size_t(0),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

which copies a dynamically allocated device pointer onto a symbol which can be used directly in device code.

---

EDIT: Answering this question is a bit like hitting a moving target. For the constant memory case you now seem interested in, here is a complete working example:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define nn (10)

__constant__ float a[nn];

__global__ void kernel(float *out)
{
    if (threadIdx.x < nn)
        out[threadIdx.x] = a[threadIdx.x];

}

int main()
{
    const size_t sz = size_t(nn) * sizeof(float);
    const float avals[nn]={ 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10. };
    float ah[nn];

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol("a", &avals[0], sz, size_t(0),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    float *ad;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&ad, sz);

    kernel<<<dim3(1),dim3(16)>>>(ad);

    cudaMemcpy(&ah[0],ad,sz,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<nn; i++) {
        printf("%d %f\n", i, ah[i]);
    }
}
```

This shows copying data onto a constant memory symbol, and using that data inside a kernel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79121/cuda-global-as-in-c-dynamic-arrays-allocated-to-device-memory

Comment: Hi actually I need to access 'a' inside the device functions and I need to modify it then I need to copy that to host.. How can I do that??

Comment: I could not modify the value of the array a inside the device code. How can I do that??

Comment: Saying "google it" isn't exactly helpful for people who get to this page by doing just that.